# I have to run cypress component Test but my application is taking approx 17 mins to bootup. So, it is creating timeout error

Tags: cmd, cypress, package.json, cypress-component-test-runner

I am using start-server-and-test but it is giving timeout error after 10 mins. I am following [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Boot-your-server) only.

Another package that I used is npm wait-on but it is also not working

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cd ../../ && npm run start",
    "run:component": "cypress run --spec integration/component_test/*.spec.js",
    "componentTest": "npm run dev  wait-on  http://localhost:3000/ && run:component",
    
  },
```

I am running `npm run componentTest`, but it is not running NEXT_CMD command, i.e. `run:component`.

Comment: There's something seriously wrong with an app that takes 17 minutes to start.

Comment: If you can share some code, there may be ways around it.

Comment: @TesterDick Yes, Webpack configuration is taking time to build. I have given snapshot of package.json. What I want from 
`"componentTest": "npm run dev wait-on localhost:3000 && run:component"`
**wait-on** should wait for localhost:3000 to be up and once up next_cmd command i.e. **run:component** should run. But currently next_cmd is not running.

Answer (score 2):

`wait-on` has a `--httpTimeout` option, maybe this will work

```js
"componentTest": "npm run dev wait-on --httpTimeout 1020000 http://localhost:3000/ && run:component"
```

Comment: I have tried this but httpTimeout  is not working .
1. `npm run dev`  opens the http://localhost:3000/ in the browser 
2. wait-on never gets timeout and hence next_cmd doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Looks like there is some serious issue with wait-on package. If you use wait-on in the initial it will work as given below but it will not fulfill the requirement
`"componentTest": "wait-on --timeout 10200 http://localhost:3000/ dev && run:component"`

Comment: Is there any way to increase the timeout period of **start-server-and-test** npm package?

Comment: I'll try it out, there must be a way since it's documented. Can't see any issues raised.

Comment: Yes, Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Abhishek, there is, but you must install *cross-env* and then use it beofre the *start-server-and-test* command. In the end you're writing "ci-test": "cross-env WAIT_ON_TIMEOUT=60000 start-server-and-test ...., where WAIT_ON_TIMEOUT is in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially wait multiple times and ignore the exit status of all but the last wait invocation.

---

However I think the main issue here is that `run dev` and `wait-on` is not propely running in paralell. Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/glemiere/3282c3ace9417b32c75d93d7f0d3086d) the proper invocation should be

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cd ../../ && npm run start",
    "run:component": "cypress run --spec integration/component_test/*.spec.js",
    "componentTest": "concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000/ && npm run run:component\" --kill-others"
},
```

which will start both concurrently. I added a script similar to this in our project and it worked as intended.

---

Possibly the [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) package could be used instead of concurrently.